# How to append new FormGroup or FormControl to form

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have the following `form` in Angular created with `FormBuilder`:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = fb.group({
      'name': ['', [Validators.required],
      'surname': ['', [Validators.required],
      'email': ['', [validateEmail]],
      'address': fb.group({
          'street': [''],
          'housenumber': [''],
          'postcode': ['']
      }, { validator: fullAddressValidator })
  });
}
```

Does exist a way to programmatically append new fields such as `FormControl` or new `FormGroup` to `myForm` ?

I mean if I want to add new fields on demand or on some conditions, how to add items to the same form that is created the first time in the `constructor`?

Comment: That could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use `addControl` method of [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) class as per [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl)

So you can do as below :

```
this.myForm.addControl('newcontrol',[]);
```

Comment: I ran into this and while using a loop had to import FormArray and add it like this: 
this.myForm.addControl(i, new FormArray([])); 
similarly, you can do that with FormGroup as well to add Objects

Comment: how do i add a new formgroup inside a formgroup

Comment: @lpradhap you add it the same way. i.e. this.myForm.addControl('newcontrol', this.fb.group({ ... }))

Comment: I get Typescript complaining `Argument of type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'. Property 'validator' is missing in type 'undefined[]'` when I do this

Comment: @CodyBugstein => this.myForm.addControl('newControl', new FormControl('', Validators.required));

Comment: In angular 16 I had to import `FormControl` and use `this.myForm.addControl('newcontrol',new FormControl(''));`

Answer (score 59):

To add upon what @ranakrunal9 said.

If you would like to use **validators** with `addControl` do the following:

```
this.myForm.addControl('newControl', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
```

Just remember to add the following import

```
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
```

Reference to `addControl`: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl

Reference to `FormControl`: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, you could just use an intermediate variable for this purpose. Take a look at the next example:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    let group = {
      'name': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'surname': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'email': ['', [Validators.required]]
    };

    let middlename = true;

    if(middlename) {
      group['middlename'] = ['', [Validators.required]];
    }

      this.myForm = fb.group(group);
    }
```

Also, it would a better idea to transfer a form initiation in ngOnInit hook, instead of component constructor.

Comment: This is my first implementation, but i prefer to use the @ranakrunal9 's solution. Anyway why it is a better idea to create form in ngOnInit hook?

Comment: Boris Siscanu: can you tell me why it's better to initiate the form in ngOnInit instead of constructor?

Comment: Angular documentation says to initiate it in the Component constructor: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-formbuilder

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but since I already have a empty FormGroup `{}` inside the main FormGroup I was able to append FormControls like this:

```
(this.myForm.get("form_group_name") as FormGroup).addControl("item1", new FormControl("default val"));
```