# Angular 14 - To add dynamically a new field form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this method which is called in the "ngOnInit" event:

```
public form!: FormGroup;

initForm(calendar?: Calendar) {
    const baseForm = this.fb.group({
      [FORM_INPUT.START_DATE]: [{
        value: calendar && this.isSomeCardSelected ? calendar.startDate : '',
        disabled: false,
      }, [this.customValidationsService.dateValidator()]],
      [FORM_INPUT.END_DATE]: [{
        value: calendar && this.isSomeCardSelected ? calendar.endDate : '',
        disabled: false,
      }, [this.customValidationsService.dateValidator()]],
    });
if (this.isDateStartHiring) {
 //The code that adds the new field "START_DATE_HIRING" should go right here. I tried it in several ways, but when I execute the form it keeps launching the date validation, which is fine for me to launch, but it should be null and not show any error.
}
    this.form = baseForm;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.initFormSubscriptions();
    }
```

I need to dynamically add a new field (`isDateStartHiring` this variable is set to true, simply by selecting a specific option from a dropdown):

```
[FORM_INPUT.START_DATE_HIRING]: [{value: calendar && calendar.startContractDate && 
this.isSomeCardSelected ? calendar.startContractDate : '', disabled: false}, [this.customValidationsService.dateValidator()]],
    });]],
```

This is the validator method:

```
  public dateValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      const value = control.value;
      if (!(value instanceof Date) || isNaN(value.getTime())) {
        if (value === '') return {dateRequired: true};
        return {dateValidator: true};
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

I want to add it dynamically because when I press a save button I get the validation: this.customValidationsService.dateValidator() although all 3 date fields have a default value i.e. the status of each field is false hence the value of this .form.valid is also false and does not access the if, if the fields are filled state of the form should be true:

```
  submit() {
    if(this.form.valid) {
 }
```

This is the html form field:

```
<div *ngIf="isDateStartHiring">
<input placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" matInput [max]="" [matDatepicker]="picker3"[formControlName]="FORM_INPUT.START_DATE_HIRING" [id]="FORM_INPUT.START_DATE_HIRING" [name]="FORM_INPUT.START_DATE_HIRING">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker3">
<svg class="icon" matDatepickerToggleIcon width="24</svg>
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker3></mat-datepicker>
</div>
```

This problem occurs because from a drop-down menu I select different options: 3 of them have the 2 fields START_DATE and END_DATE and the 4th option is the one that maintains the 2 fields and adds START_DATE_HIRING and is the one that does not work.

Comment: Just add a new form control => https://stackoverflow.com/a/41588389/9349240

Answer (score 1):

Check this code snippet

```
public dateValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      const value = control.value;
      if (!(value instanceof Date) || isNaN(value.getTime())) {
        if (value === '') return {dateRequired: true};
        return {dateValidator: true};
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

Usually the validator fn should take a parameter, which is the control: AbstractControl. Is this valid in your code? i don't see where do you get from this control if you didn't specify in the param list.

Comment: control.value contains the value entered in the date input of each of the fields

Comment: The dateValidator method was not correct, I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

what the type of the

```
this.isDateStartHiring
```

variable is? How do you set it to false or true? Check if that is set is working or not.

You can use addControl or removeControl method from [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl) depending on the isDateStartHiring variable.

Comment: isDateStartHiring is a boolean variable, in the ngOnInit event if calendarTypeId is 3 (value get from BBDD) isDateStartHiring would equal true

Comment: Added the use of the isDateStartHiring variable in the html

Comment: Than just add the new fromcontrol to the formgroup:
this.baseForm.addControl('name', new FormControl(''));

Comment: The dateValidator method was not correct, I have corrected it